# Shopify: How to edit the HTML / Liquid on the checkout page?

Tags: shopify

I just started a shopify store and I want to edit the HTML or Liquid on the checkout page when someone presses "Proceed to Checkout". However, I don't see any template for that in my template editor. Where is this view file?

It looks like it's being redirect to something shopify hosts. The domain changes from myshop.shopify.com to something like https://checkout.shopify.com/carts/47974257/18b0c50ab2bce29f0000e137987g05c8c

Can someone help???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See here: [is it possible to create a checkout template?](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/is-it-possible-to-create-a-checkout-template-149722)

> You can only customize your checkout by editing the checkouts CSS. Shopify must control the majority of your checkout in order to ensure PCI level 1 compliance to protect both you and your customers from potential unscrupulous behaviour on the checkout.shopify.com server.

<s>See here to edit the checkout CSS: [Customizing your checkout CSS](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/checkout-page/checkout-css)</s>

**Update:** For Shopify Plus, see [checkout.liquid](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/layouts/checkout-liquid) and [checkout.scss.liquid](https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/templates/checkout-scss-liquid). Otherwise, [see here](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/order-status#advanced-customizations):

> If you're on a non-plus subscription, you can customize your checkout in the theme editor by clicking **Customize checkout** on the **Checkout** page of your Shopify admin.

There is also the [Additional Content & Scripts](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/order-status#add-additional-scripts) area in Settings.

Comment: The Shopify answer pages you link to are no longer active; has Shopify removed the ability to edit CSS for the Checkout page?

Comment: @emunsing also see https://help.shopify.com/themes/development/templates/checkout-scss-liquid

Comment: This URL is no longer valid `http://docs.shopify.com/support/settings/checkout-and-payment/how-do-i-customize-my-thank-you-page#additional`

Comment: For non-plus, now you go to the theme, then Customize, Theme Settings and Checkout.

Answer (score 4):

Shopify completely explains how you can override the CSS presented in the checkout on their domain so that it matches your theme. You cannot alter any HTML or Javascript. You can however alter the final step of checkout, the Thank You page.

If you are Shopify Plus member, you can totally mess with checkout as they give you access to checkout.liquid

Comment: I wouldn't say you can "totally mess with checkout" if you are shopify plus.  There is still much that you can't control, but you do have access to the checkout.liquid page. However, the main flow of the checkout and process is controlled by shopify through the {{ content_for_layout }} which you are required to include.

Comment: You are forgetting that you can script checkout on Plus plans. That means you can eliminate a whole host of cheesy Apps that fudge things, and write totally logical scripts that determine pricing. We are not talking superficial stuff like CSS and HTML anymore.

Comment: The Shopify answer pages which were linked to in the other answer are no longer active (as of October 2016); has Shopify removed the ability to edit CSS for the Checkout page?